# how to simple connect to my sharePoint and get all the documents ?

Tags: development, .net, client

i need to write a C# code that can connect to my sharePoint and get all the documents and also upload some new document.

I can't find any simple example code that can do it

any help please ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args) {  
    var site = new ClientContext("http://sitename/");  
    var web = site.Web;  
    site.Load(web);  
    site.ExecuteQuery();  
    // Library name - Shared Documents  
    List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");  
    site.Load(list);  
    site.ExecuteQuery();  
    site.Load(list.RootFolder);  
    site.ExecuteQuery();  
    site.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);  
    site.ExecuteQuery();  
    processFolderClientobj(list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl);  
    foreach(Folder folder in list.RootFolder.Folders) {  
        processFolderClientobj(folder.ServerRelativeUrl);  
    }  
}  
public static void processFolderClientobj(string folderURL) {  
    string Destination = @  
    "c:\\temp";  
    var site = new ClientContext("http://sitename/");  
    var web = site.Web;  
    site.Load(web);  
    site.ExecuteQuery();  
    Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderURL);  
    site.Load(folder);  
    site.ExecuteQuery();  
    site.Load(folder.Files);  
    site.ExecuteQuery();  
    foreach(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in folder.Files) {  
        string destinationfolder = Destination + "/" + folder.ServerRelativeUrl;  
        Stream fs = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(site, file.ServerRelativeUrl).Stream;  
        byte[] binary = ReadFully(fs);  
        if (!Directory.Exists(destinationfolder)) {  
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationfolder);  
        }  
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(destinationfolder + "/" + file.Name, FileMode.Create);  
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);  
        writer.Write(binary);  
        writer.Close();  
    }  
}  
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input) {  
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];  
    using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {  
        int read;  
        while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {  
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);  
        }  
        return ms.ToArray();  
    }  
}
```

Ref [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/1439/download-all-files-from-sharepoint-document-library.aspx) for PowerShell and SharePoint Object Model.